# Create a custom PopUp WPF that works for different types

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new working with WPF and I'd like to know if it's possible to create a PopUp user control with a ListBox that can accept any class for its items?.

I have here the xaml code for a list of objects of the class 'Tipo', but I'd like to use this user control for another class, let's say the class 'Person'

```
<UserControl 

...

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:BoolToInvertedBoolConverter x:Key="converter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>


    <Grid x:Name="gridPrincipal">

        <ToggleButton x:Name="tbTipo" Grid.Row="0" Background="{Binding Path=ColorFondo}" Foreground="{Binding Path=ColorTexto}" Opacity="1" Content="{Binding Path=ContenidoToggleButton}" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Popup1, Path=IsOpen, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />

        <Popup x:Name="Popup1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" AllowsTransparency="True"  Placement="MousePoint" Focusable="False" StaysOpen="False" PopupAnimation="Slide" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=tbTipo}" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=tbTipo, Mode=TwoWay}" >

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >

                <Grid Margin="0,10,0,0" Background="LightBlue" Height="Auto">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <CheckBox Name="chkTodos" Grid.Column="2" Content="Seleccionar todos" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" MinHeight="25" Margin="0,0,10,0" IsChecked="{Binding SeleccionarTodos}" />
                </Grid>

                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="550" MaxWidth="400" Opacity="0.9">
                    <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                            <ListBox Name="lbTipo" ItemsSource="{Binding ListTipos, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="LightGray" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Tipo}">
                                        <DataTemplate.Resources>
                                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue"/>
                                        </DataTemplate.Resources>

                                        <Grid Background="{Binding Path=ColorVigencia}" >
                                            <CheckBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Focusable="False" Content="{Binding Descripcion}" />
                                        </Grid>


                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </StackPanel>



        </Popup>


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in there where you specify that the `ItemsSource` must be a `List<Tipo>`.  The problem that you will run into is that your button binds to `Descripcion` and `IsChecked`, which are not properties of most other classes.  You could create an Interface that says that all classes which inherit it must have properties called `Descripcion` and `IsChecked`.  then it would be safe to use for any class that implements that interface.

Comment: Hello, thank you for response.  I specify that here: `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListTipos, Mode=TwoWay}" `  I think that that's the solution, to create an Interface and binding it to the ListBox Items, and all the class that I want to use with the control need to implement my interface.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do it with Data Templates. In this way you just set the ItemsSource for the ListBox and WPF figures out what data template to use based on the object type.

Heres an example from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_wpf_data_templates.htm

```
<UserControl.Resources> 

   <DataTemplate DataType = "{x:Type data:Student}">

      <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal"> 
         <TextBox Text = "{Binding Path = FirstName, Mode = TwoWay}" 
            Width = "100" Margin = "3 5 3 5"/> 

         <TextBox Text = "{Binding Path = LastName, Mode = TwoWay}" 
            Width = "100" Margin = "0 5 3 5"/> 

         <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Path = FullName, Mode = OneWay}" 
            Margin = "0 5 3 5"/> 

      </StackPanel> 

   </DataTemplate> 
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid> 
   <ListBox ItemsSource = "{Binding Students}"/> 
</Grid>
```